# APIGEETool DeployNodeApp

Tags: apigee

We are trying to use the apigeetool deploynodeapp utility to deploy a node.js app to apigee.

We think we are following the instructions properly, but are getting a "broken pipe" error every time we try.

The command we are running is...

`apigeetool deploynodeapp -n sampleService -d . -m server.js -o ourOrgNameHere -e test -b sample -u ourUserName -p ourPassword`

Obviously, ourOrgNameHere, ourUserName, and ourPassword are not the values we really used.

When we run that from the command line, there is a 20 second pause, followed by the output below...

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/apigeetool", line 24, in <module>
    deploynodeapp.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ApigeePlatformTools/deploynodeapp.py", line 180, in run
    revision = deploytools.importBundle(Organization, Name, tf.getvalue())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ApigeePlatformTools/deploytools.py", line 115, in importBundle
    resp = httptools.httpCall('POST', uri, hdrs, data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ApigeePlatformTools/httptools.py", line 24, in httpCall
    conn.request(verb, uri, body, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1007, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 805, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 229, in sendall
    v = self.send(data[count:])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 198, in send
    v = self._sslobj.write(data)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your command line looks correct.  I tried this just now and it worked for me with no problems.  If there was a problem with your credentials, you would have gotten a 401 error.

Comment: The error you are getting is not consistent with credentials problems, or improper org/environment names.  Are you able to get the sample node script at http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/deploying-standalone-nodejs-app to deploy, or are they the same script?  I tried it just now and it worked for me.  Can you cut/paste the commands and script on that page and see if that works?  If you are still stuck, I can try it from my end to see if it works for me.

Comment: Ok.  I was able to grab the very simple sample at the link above and get that to work.  That's progress, but I'm afraid I'm still in the dark.  I asked a few days ago and was told that I needed a package.json and several things in it.  But, I don't seem to really need it since that sample worked without it.  Now I'm on to my next hurdle.  I probably do need a package.json because my app does have some dependencies on some npm libraries that aren't part of the apigee default list.  So, I'm afraid I'm still going to need help figuring this out.

Comment: I'm getting closer.  I was able to get one uploaded.  And, it includes a reference to another library called sqs.  So far so good.

Comment: Now, I get this error...  

    {
       "fault":
       {
           "faultstring": "Script executed prematurely: invalid string escape mask (/organizations/myorg/environments/prod/apis/hellonode/node_modules/sqs/index.js#54)",
           "detail":
           {
               "errorcode": "messaging.runtime.ScriptExitedError"
           }
       }
    }

If I require sqs (so it's a dependency of mine) and it, in turn, has dependencies...  Do I need to somehow tell Apigee about the cascading dependencies?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Can you tell us the size of the generated zip of the original failed deployment?  I'm thinking the broken pipe is result of the generated zipped file size being too big.  You can use the -z option to just create the zip.

Regarding the cascading dependencies:  apigeetool will zip up everything below the root of your proxy directory (-d), so there _should_ _not_ be a dependency issue.  I assume your node.js program  works locally.  Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to tell Apigee about the Node module dependencies. The apigeetool utility is supposed to (by default) resolve your Node.js dependencies automatically after your project is uploaded to Apigee Edge (as if running npm install on Edge itself).

Some users have found that if this fails for some reason, it works if you use the --upload-modules option like this:

apigeetool deploynodeapp --upload-modules

The upload-modules flag tells the tool to zip and upload all the modules from your system (rather than trying to update them on Edge). As long as your Node.js works locally, it should work when you deploy it. Try using --upload-modules to see if that works for you.